# Change directory in server is not changing when trying from client - ruby

Tags: ruby, ssh, cd, net-ssh

This is small part of my code. If this is not sufficient, i will the post full code.
I have few commands to execute in the server and everything works fine except changing directory `cd` command using `require 'net/ssh'`.

I have tried with both `cd` and `Dir.chdir`but no luck. Here `@action` is my directory name.

```
 puts @ssh.exec!('pwd')
 @ssh.exec!("cd ./#{@action}")
 puts @ssh.exec!('pwd')
```

I tried to print present working directory before and after executing the command and it shows the same path without going to the required path.

Comment: Why `Dir.chdir` no use? Use `Dir.getwd` to see current directory.

Comment: either of 'cd' or `Dir.chdir` is not helping me to change directory in server.